# Proof that shows existence of a real number between any two real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove: Let $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $x < y$. There exists a $z\in\Bbb
> R$ such that $x < z < y$.
>
> Given:
>
> Axiom $8.1$. For all $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$:
>
> $(i)~~~~x + y = y + x\\ (ii)~~(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)\\ (iii)~x*(y +
> z) = x*y + x*z\\ (iv)~~x*y = y*x\\ (v)~~~(x*y)*z = x*(y*z)$
>
> Axiom $8.2$. There exists a real number $0$ such that for all
>   $z\in\Bbb R, x + 0 = x$.
>
> Axiom $8.3$. There exists a real number $1$ such that $1 ≠ 0$ and
>   whenever $x\in\Bbb R, x*1 = x$.
>
> Axiom $8.4$. For each $x\in\Bbb R$, there exists a real number,
>   denoted by $-x$, such that $x+(-x) = 0$.
>
> Axiom $8.5$. For each $x\in\Bbb R-\{0\}$, there exists a number,
>   denoted by $x^{-1}$, such that $x*x^{-1} = 1$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon = \frac{y-x}{2} $

$\epsilon$ is a real number greater than $0$, so $x +\epsilon > x$

Now I have to prove $x +\epsilon < y$, but I'm having difficulty.

Is it easier to prove the above way, or prove that

$y -\epsilon <y $ 
then

$x +\epsilon = y +\epsilon$

Comment: To prove $x+\epsilon<y$ note  $x+\epsilon=\frac{y+x}2<\frac{y+y}2=y$

Comment: $x<x+\epsilon=y-\epsilon<y$

Comment: And you need Archimede's axiom to show that there is a rational between any two reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your axioms don't characterize all the properties of real numbers you need. For example you need
**Axiom**: If $x<y$ then $x+z<y+z$ for all $z$, and $xz<yz$ for all $z>0$.

Now you can put $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$ or $z=x+\epsilon$ as you defined.
**Proof**: Since $x<y$, we have $2x=x+x<x+y<y+y=2y$. Hence, $x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$.

Comment: Thank you for such an elegant answer!